# Is there any way to add a line or vertical sparation before the next date in org-agenda-view

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I would like to add a line to separate the current block of tasks from the next date, so the last task of the date is not just above the next date.

[image]

I know I can use `:box` with `set-face-attribute 'org-agenda-date` for , but is a solution that it has some inconveniences. So I would like to add a line if possible or a separation between those blocks.

Comment: If the `org-agenda.el` library has been loaded, then type `M-x find-function RET org-agenda-format-date-aligned RET`.  If the library has not loaded, type:  `M-x eval-expression RET (require 'org-agenda) RET`.  See the last line of the function where it states `(format "%-10s %2d %s %4d%s" dayname day monthname year weekstring)`?  You might want to try adding `\n` to the beginning so that it looks like `(format "\n%-10s %2d %s %4d%s" dayname day monthname year weekstring)`.  You can copy the function to a `*scratch*` buffer, modify it and `M-x eval-buffer` to see if it works like you want.

Comment: Alternatively, you can grep the `org-agenda` source code for usages of `org-agenda-format-date-aligned` and `(insert "\n")` at the appropriate location(s) of the function(s) responsible for inserting that date line.  Note that these types of modifications have *not* been tested and may break other aspects of org-agenda, e.g., things like bulk marking/editing, etc ....  You will need to do your own testing to see if anything breaks, and if so, what else needs fixing.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, even though I used another position (`org-agenda-finalize-entries`) it was very helpful your comment.